# rendering a radiobuttonlist to show options in one line

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i created a radio button list with male or female options.

but when it is rendered it is generating each option in each row. I want both the options to be rendered in one row?

Like this: O Male  O Fmale
Can i do that?

Comment: is this mvc or web forms? if it's mvc, the below answers are incorrect. if it's mvc, show the code your using to render the radio button list, as there is no built in helper to do that (only a single radio button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property of the RadioButtonList called RepeatDirection

RepeatDirection="Horizontal" is what you want

Comment: According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatdirection.aspx) shouldn't it be Horizontal?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Brain fart.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I believe the property you are looking for is RadioButtonList.RepeatLayout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatlayout.aspx

setting `RepeatLayout="Span"` should do that